# How to parse OR decode the hex data from a CAN bus log file?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to know how to parse / decode the HEX data from the CAN-LOG file. (it's a csv file)

This file is from CAN (**Controller Area Network**)bus that will be used in automobiles for communication between different ECUs.

I would like to decode the following data bytes (the data from following columns) from this log file:

I would like to know whether is there any specific parser with respect to this CAN bus data?

ID,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8 (all these columns have data in HEX format)

For example :

```
TYPE,TIME,ID,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,ASCII,COUNT,PERIOD,,
RD11,4.2386,424,3,0,C,0,0,16,1,FF,        ,107,0.0397,,
RD11,4.2394,375,F,F,0,0,0,0,0,0,        ,43,0.1,,
RD11,4.2396,236,10,BD,F,FF,20,0,0,8C,        ,424,0.01,,
```

i have tried this function:

```
bytes.fromhex('30C00161FF').decode('utf-8')
```

also tried this function

```
binascii.unhexlify('1C3C00FFFFFFFF')
```

But i am not able to extract parameters like temperature, velocity, acceleration etc.

The ID column has names Temperature, velocity and columns D1 to D8 has values with respect to these parameters.

Comment: int('0x'+variable,0) is a good candidate for hex conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
def parse_line(line):
    spl = line.split(',')
    return (spl[0], float(spl[1]), int('0x'+spl[2],0), int('0x'+spl[3],0), int('0x'+spl[4],0), int('0x'+spl[5],0), int('0x'+spl[6],0), int('0x'+spl[7],0), int('0x'+spl[8],0), int('0x'+spl[9],0), int('0x'+spl[10],0), spl[11], int(spl[12]), float(spl[13]))
```

Can be used like :

```
line1="RD11,4.2386,424,3,0,C,0,0,16,1,FF,        ,107,0.0397,,"
line2="RD11,4.2394,375,F,F,0,0,0,0,0,0,        ,43,0.1,,"
line3="RD11,4.2396,236,10,BD,F,FF,20,0,0,8C,        ,424,0.01,,"
print parse_line(line2)
print parse_line(line3)
print parse_line(line4)
```

and outputs

> ('RD11', 4.2386, 1060, 3, 0, 12, 0, 0, 22, 1, 255, '        ', 107, 0.0397)
>   ('RD11', 4.2394, 885, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '        ', 43, 0.1)
>   ('RD11', 4.2396, 566, 16, 189, 15, 255, 32, 0, 0, 140, '        ', 424, 0.01)

Comment: Thank you ! i think this must help will revert once executed.

Comment: Did not quite get the comment. But if my post answers your question dont hesitate to accept the answer. Good day

Comment: It did not serve my purpose as I expected. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question to make it clearer because I dont get how it does not answer your question.

Comment: Your solution will do the job of converting from hex to int. But as I was was new to reading CAN bus data, but to know which ID belongs to which parameter has to be checked live by experimenting and we will get values but will not come to know which bits are varying for which parameter and on what logic the variation is based. There is nothing wrong in your solution in converting to int from hex. Hence, it was not the solution that i expected. This CAN data doesn't decode anything. It is a tedious process. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your CAN data looks strange. I'm more accustomed to CANDump or CANvas data, which is usually something like `18fedf00;7da0287d7dfffff0`: a SPN/PGN followed by the data itself. The SPN will tell you how to decode the data, depending on the manufacturer and year.

Maybe, for instance, your third data point is SPN 236, "Engine Total Idle Fuel Used"? But I don't know what 424 and 375 are, so maybe I'm reading your data wrong.

I wrote this tool a while back for dealing with small amounts of generic CAN data:
https://api.greencam.xyz/canbus

It may help you.
Brett